# best performance between LowerCase Pipe , LowerCase css and LowerCase string method in create angular app

Tags: angular

If I want to start a big scale angular app which has a lot of string manipulation what is the best practice and performance for ChangeDetection? Which one is the best?

1.LowerCase Pipe
2.LowerCase css
3.ToLowerCase string method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. LowerCase Pipe should be a good option as pipes are optimized for performance concerning ChangeDetection.
2. LowerCase CSS, I am not sure how this would perform.
3. ToLowerCase string method is not a good option as it would be called every time ChangeDetection runs.